# Unexpected behavior of frozen/2

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, prolog-coroutining

I was playing around with the [prolog-coroutining](/questions/tagged/prolog-coroutining) predicates `freeze/2` and `frozen/2`:

```
?- freeze(X,a=a), frozen(X,Goal).
?- freeze(X,a=a), freeze(Y,b=b), X=Y, frozen(X,Goal).
```

[sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) (version 4.5.1 for x86_64) gave these answers:

```
| ?- freeze(X,a=a), frozen(X,Goal).
Goal = prolog:freeze(X,user:(a=a)),
prolog:freeze(X,user:(a=a)) ? ;
no
| ?- freeze(X,a=a), freeze(Y,b=b), X=Y, frozen(X,Goal).
Y = X,
Goal = (user:(a=a),prolog:freeze(X,user:(b=b))),
prolog:freeze(X,user:(a=a)),
prolog:freeze(X,user:(b=b)) ? ;
no
```

Now `Goal = prolog:freeze(X,user:(a=a))` I did not expect!

What I *did* expect were answers like the ones given by [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) version 8.0.3:

```
?- freeze(X,a=a), frozen(X,Goal).
Goal = user:(a=a),
freeze(X, a=a).
?- freeze(X,a=a), freeze(Y,b=b), X=Y, frozen(X,Goal).
X = Y,
Goal = (user:(a=a), user:(b=b)),
freeze(Y, a=a),
freeze(Y, b=b).
```

Arguably, both the SICStus answers *and* the SWI answers are correct...

**But is there a deeper reason for the somewhat peculiar answer(s) given by SICStus?**

Comment: AFAIK in Sicstus the functionality for masking "last failure" is not implemented ` ? ; 
no`

Comment: For one, explicit qualification is preferable.

Comment: Up to 3.8.5 this problem does not exist. From 3.8.6 on it does exist.

Comment: @AntonDanilov. Okay. But I was actually referring to differences in the bold lines "Goal = ...".

Comment: @false. What are you referring to when you're speaking of "explicit qualification" ?

Comment: By explicit qualification I meant explicit module prefix.  That is `prolog:` in place of nothing (as shown by SWI)

Comment: In any case: It seems no-one is using this interface any longer. And I would rather prefer two `freeze/2` goals.

Comment: `prolog:` is the module for builtins. in SWI  is no such module

Comment: @AntonDanilov: In SWI there is a `system` module. Just say `git grep system:` in the sources.

Comment: Maybe @PerMildner will answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there is any "deep" reason for the difference. Since `frozen/2` is a general interface to attributed variables, it kind of makes sense to not special-case `freeze/2` goals.

In fact, up to 4.5.1, SICStus tried, but sometimes failed, to special-case `freeze/2` goals. This is why you see `user:(a=a)` for the first sub-goal. In the next release we have changed this so the result instead will become `Goal = (prolog:freeze(X,user:(a=a)),prolog:freeze(X,user:(b=b)))` (and we have also made some other improvements to `frozen/2`).

Comment: *up to 4,5,1* and after 3.8.5